# Restrict clipboard for untrusted X11 clients

Tags: x11, security, xorg, users, sandbox

I've came across this blog https://notehub.org/rp5n2 which describes a way to make certain X11 clients *untrusted*[1], which makes certain X11 extensions unavailable to them. Note that I know perfectly well that this alone is worthless unless I also use UID separation, which I do. I use `xsudo`[2] to run crapware.

However, even with untrusted connection, clients can still monitor the clipboard. If the user is `crapware`, programs running under its account can still monitor the primary selection. Just try:

```
watch -n0.5 xsudo crapware xclip -o
```

The security extensions is definitely useful as it prevents untrusted X11 clients to log keyboard or simulate keypresses but sniffing on clipboard is a weakness. How can I prevent sharing clipboard with untrusted X11 clients by default?

I'm not interested in things like firejail. I don't care about namespaces. UNIX user separation is all I need. I also would like to avoid Xpra. It's way way waaay too slow compared to clients directly connected to X11. You can really notice the lag when typing.

[1] https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/xextproto/security.html

[2]

```
#!/bin/zsh
set -e

# Copied from https://notehub.org/rp5n2

if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 asuser [cmdline...]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

asuser=$1
shift

if [[ -z $DISPLAY ]]; then
    echo "DISPLAY is not set" >&2
    exit 1
fi

cookie=/tmp/.Xauthority-$DISPLAY-$asuser

if [[ ! -e $cookie ]]; then
    touch $cookie
    chmod 600 $cookie
    xauth -f $cookie generate $DISPLAY MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted
    sudo chgrp $asuser $cookie
    chmod 660 $cookie
fi

export XAUTHORITY=$cookie

if [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; then
    exec sudo -u $asuser "$@"
else
    exec sudo -u $asuser -i
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use nested X server [nxagent](https://packages.debian.org/experimental/nxagent) instead of xpra, it is way faster for local setups.

`nxagent` provides a seamless mode for single apps, too. It is a bit itchy to set it up in seamless mode and without clipboard and with its own Xauthority cookie. You can use [x11docker](https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker) for easy usage:

```
x11docker --nxagent --exe -- yourapplication
```

or short:

```
x11docker -ne yourapplication
```

To run as another user:

```
sudo x11docker --user someuser -ne -- yourapplication
```

To allow clipboard sharing, add x11docker option `--clipboard`. nxagent allows it per default, but x11docker disables it unless specified.

If you need hardware acceleration, install `xpra`, `Xwayland`,`weston` and `xdotool` and run

```
sudo x11docker --user someuser --xpra-xwayland --exe -- yourapplication
```

---

Setup with nxagent only and without a cookie for clients:

```
echo "nx/nx,clipboard=none:25" >/tmp/nxoptions
nxagent :25 -R -nolisten tcp -options /tmp/nxoptions
sudo -u someuser env DISPLAY=:25 yourapplication
```

This works with US keyboard only. To get another keyboard layout, change `/tmp/nxoptions`. For german keyboard layout:

```
echo "nx/nx,clipboard=none,keyboard=evdev/de:25" >/tmp/nxoptions
```

---

Another possibility is to use Xephyr as nested X server. But it does not provide a seamless mode.

```
Xephyr :10
sudo -u someuser env DISPLAY=:10 openbox  # provide a window manager
sudo -u someuser env DISPLAY=:10 someapplication
```

For hardware acceleration with Xephyr you can use `virtualgl`. (But may be a bit tricky with a different user as virtualgl/`vglrun` needs access to display :0).